# Video Player Controllers are not working After Playing Video Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to play video from local and put it in a slider, video is playing but one the play button are disappear nothing is working in the video.

```
playVideo () {
      guard let videoPath =      NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(files.fileImage, ofType: "mp4")
           else {

                    print ("Error")
                    break
                }

                let player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath))
                let playerController =  AVPlayerViewController()
                playerController.player = player
                playerController.view.frame = svSlider.frame
                playerController.showsPlaybackControls = true
                let videoPlayerView = playerController.view
                videoPlayerView.frame =  svSlider.frame 
                self.svSlider.addSubview(videoPlayerView)
                fromLeft += videoPlayerView.frame.width

}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: the buttons disappear, and then nothing works anymore? Is that it?

Comment: means when one after some time video player controls disappear its not coming after tapping the player.